# Rails: How can I get a users profile picture through the Facebook API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook API/omniauth so that users sign up through my site using their Facebook account, but I'm trying to figure out how I can set up their 'profile' area. I want their current Facebook picture to be their current picture on my site.

Answer (score 1):

In your user model, in the `from_omniauth` method, you can add

```
   user.avatar = auth.info.image
```

This line will obtain the image of the user and save in in the column `avatar` of type string, you should create that column in your user table first.